# Installing vim/emacs on solaris 8

Tags: vim, solaris, emacs

At my new job, they want me to use a solaris 8 operating system, but all my coding experience has been on linux. Linux had a lot of tools built into the system, but it seems like the solaris I'm using is extremely stripped down.

I was wondering if someone can tell me how to install vim or emacs (preferably emacs) on solaris 8. I tried google but I couldn't find any download links for solaris 8. I tried using vi, but it's a little annoying to use after using vim and emacs (I can't even get the editor to backspace correctly!). Also, there is no syntax highlighting in vi which is a little annoying. Can anyone here help me install a more modern text editor? (And also help me become a little more proficient in solaris 8 :) ). 
Thank you.

Comment: short version like on every other system: unpack, ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local ; make ; make install. Btw. it seems solaris 8 reached EOL see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  http://www.sunfreeware.com was the place to go to get pre-built packages for FOSS software on Solaris (so you can run the `pkgadd` command), but it looks like they don't support the older versions, like Solaris 8.

They refer you to unixpackages.com.  Here's the Sparc Solaris 8 page: http://unixpackages.com/package-list-sparcsolaris-8

(you're doing this on Sparc? there's also the X86 list in a dropdown)

but it looks like you have to buy a subscription to access those packages.  Since this is for work and they're making you use Solaris 8, you can see if they want to spring for it.

Pondering Ulrich's suggestion, I checked to see how one would install gcc on Solaris in this day and age and found this:

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

The Solaris section points to a number of other sites that have pre-built packages for Solaris.  Take a look at those.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up to cjc's answer, I was able to find the file names at the [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20070601000000*/http://sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc8.html) to track down the file names. Searching for them let me to [this repository](http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/8) that can be used in place of sunfreeeware. Armed with this, I chose to install version 7.0 of vim as 7.3 has a [crap-ton more dependencies.](https://web.archive.org/web/20110728090308/http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc8.html)

Downloading the following files:

http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/8/vim-7.0-sol8-sparc-local.gz
http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/8/ncurses-5.6-sol8-sparc-local.gz
http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/8/gtk+-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local.gz
http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/8/glib-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local.gz

And then running the following commands installed vim for me:

```
gunzip vim-7.0-sol8-sparc-local.gz
gunzip ncurses-5.6-sol8-sparc-local.gz
gunzip gtk+-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local.gz
gunzip glib-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local.gz

pkgadd -d vim-7.0-sol8-sparc-local
pkgadd -d ncurses-5.6-sol8-sparc-local
pkgadd -d gtk+-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local
pkgadd -d glib-1.2.10-sol8-sparc-local
```

You may also need a symlink or to update your default PATH

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /opt/local/bin/vim
```